# Google play is not displaying

Tags: google-play-store

I'm trying to open google play on my computer but it displays me like below image:

[image]

Doesn't display any of the application not even when I select from categories.

Comment: For what it's worth, this would probably be better off at [webapps.se]. Where are you connecting from? Is this in all browsers?

Comment: @user267 Yes, coming on all browsers. And I want to install apps from there.

Comment: And? Where are you connecting from? Do you have issues with any other websites, especially anything else on google.com? Are you on a corporate network/using a proxy? Does the Google Play app on your device work correctly?

Comment: AdBlock? NoScript? Ghostery? Other filters? But as said above: It's not an Android related question, even if it deals with a website offering Android Apps. So it rather belongs somewhere else...